# Net::HTTP failure to access Google Docs List Data API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-docs-api, google-data-api

I am trying to consume the Google Docs List Data API Version 3.0 using Net::HTTP in ruby using the following code.

```
require 'net/http'

spreadsheets_uri = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full'
docs_uri = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3"

def get_feed(uri, headers=nil)
  uri = URI.parse(uri)
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    return http.get(uri.path, headers)
  end 
end

def get_headers(service)
  http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com', 443)
  http.use_ssl = true
  path = '/accounts/ClientLogin'
  data = "accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=#{EM}&Passwd=#{PW}&service=#{service}"
  headers = { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)

  headers["Authorization"] = "GoogleLogin auth=#{data[/Auth=(.*)/, 1]}"
  headers["GData-Version"] = "3.0"
  headers
end

puts get_feed(spreadsheets_uri, get_headers("wise")) 
puts get_feed(docs_uri, get_headers("writely"))
```

This works for

```
'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full'
```

but not for

```
 "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3"
```

which throws the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)


from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2219:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2208:in `read_new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1191:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:888:in `get'
    from ./gd.rb:9:in `block in get_feed'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:490:in `start'
    from ./gd.rb:8:in `get_feed'
    from ./gd.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the correct service name for the DocsList API when performing authentication using ClientLogin. You are using service=wise which is for the Spreadsheet API, try with service=writely for the DocsList API.

The list of service names is available at http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#clientlogin

Comment: thanks! that seems like the correct answer. unfortunately, i can't test it now because google is throwing an token invalid error--even for the unchanged code above for spreadsheets that worked before.

Comment: nope! although your answer definitely seems to address a problem in my code i still get the same error. I updated my code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include "verify_mode" option in your request. 
I changed your "get_feed" method and it works for me.

```
def get_feed(uri, headers=nil)
  uri = URI.parse(uri)
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)  
  https.use_ssl = true
  https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  https.start do |http|
    return http.get(uri.request_uri, headers)
  end 
end
```